# I need to create a filter for payload01 print compare the values of the publisher list and bring situation status and print at the end the situation

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

```
enter code here
```

var payload01 = {

```
"value_Book": "49.00",

"date_publisher": "2022-05-15"
```

}

var book = {

```
"booksList": [

    {

        "publisher": {

            "id_book": "001",

            "name": "Adams",

            "date_publisher": "2022-01-01",

            "situation": "Worn_out",

            "number_edition": "10",

            "value_Book": "49.00"

        }

    },     

    {

        "publisher": {

            "id_book": "002",

            "name": "Adams",

            "date_publisher": "2022-05-15",

            "situation": "in_stock",

            "number_edition": "5",

            "value_Book": "79.00"

        }

    }

]
```

}

Details: need to bring in a final response of the situation according to the parameters of load 1 confronting the list of books

example_body:

{
"situation": "Worn_out"
}

Comment: Please provide details of the logic to achieve the expected output with the inputs and fix the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

For the given payload (payload01) as given parameters,

```
var payload01 = {

"value_Book": "49.00",

"date_publisher": "2022-05-15"
}
```

Here is the dataweave code that will get you a list (array) of books which satisfy the specified search parameters above:

```
(book.booksList.publisher filter (($.date_publisher == payload01.date_publisher) and ($.value_Book == var.payload01.value_Book)))
```

Here is the output:

```
{
   "situation": "worn_out"
}
```

Comment: Please add the inputs and output of your script.

Comment: @aled the inputs are given by the questioner. Two variables, payload01 and book. I will output the result.

Comment: It is better to be explicit. The inputs are provided as variables, so you should incorporate them in your script.

Comment: thank you for assisting in this task